# MySQL group_concat WHERE first item in field has specific ID

Tags: mysql, where-clause, group-concat

How can I select only sessions that start/begin with a specific topic_id ('5000') and contain more than one topic_id? Code in WHERE clause in pseudo-code.

```
request_id  session_id  topic_id
1           1           3000
2           1           5000
3           2           5000
4           2           3000
5           2           6000
6           3           5000 

SELECT
min(request_id),
session_id,
group_concat(topic_id order by request_id asc SEPARATOR ' ,')
FROM requests
WHERE (first(topic_id) = '5000' AND count(topic_id) > 1)
group by session_id
order by request_id asc

result:
request_id  session_id  topic_id
3           2           5000, 3000, 6000
```

I know this should work with a sub query, but I don't know how. Thanks!!

Comment: What does "start with" a topic mean? How do we see that a session not only includes a topic but starts with it? And in a sessions table we will find one record per session, so where do we find the related topics?

Comment: I added an example of the table, so I hope this clarifies my question. "start with" means, that only sessions that begin with topic_id 5000 should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to be like below using `HAVING` clause like

```
SELECT
request_id,
session_id,
group_concat(topic_id order by request_id)
FROM sessions 
GROUP BY session_id
HAVING MIN(topic_id) = '5000' 
AND COUNT(DISTINCT topic_id) > 1
ORDER BY request_id;
```

Comment: This returns all sessions where the topic_id '5000' is the smallest value, no matter at which position 5000 has in the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by `LIKE` :

```
select * from (
SELECT
    request_id,
    session_id,
    group_concat(topic_id order by request_id asc SEPARATOR ' ,') as groups
    ,  count(topic_id) as count_topic
    FROM sessions   
    group by session_id
    order by request_id asc
    ) as temp_table
    WHERE (topic_id LIKE '5000%' AND count_topic > 1)
```

Comment: This returns an error code 1111 'Invalid use of group function'. If I exclude 'count(topic_id)>1' the query works, but returns only sessions that contain ONLY the topic_id '5000'.

Comment: Thanks! Your sub query works, if you add something like 'as sub query' after the parenthesis. But if I include 'count(topic_id) > 1 it returns the error code 1111.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult in MySQL, but not too difficult when we do it step by step:

1. get the minimum request_id per session_id (i.e. the request with the first topic per session)
2. but only consider sessions with more than one topic (with HAVING)
3. get the record with that id (in order to look at its topic_id)
4. keep only records where the topic is 5000 (you now have sessions starting with topic 5000 but also having other topics)
5. access all topic_ids for each thus found session (in a subquery)

Query:

```
select
  request_id,
  session_id,
  (
    select group_concat(topic_id order by request_id asc separator ' ,')
    from requests topics
    where topics.session_id = requests.session_id
  )
from requests
where (session_id, request_id) in
(
  select
    session_id,
    min(request_id)
  from requests
  group by session_id
  having count(distinct topic_id) > 1
)
and topic_id = 5000;
```

(I took the liberty to call the table `requests`, as it seems it is request records the table contains each referring to a session for which there is probably a separate `sessions` table.)

EDIT: As @Gouda Elalfy shows in his answer, this can be done much easier by merely looking at the concatenated topic string. He should update his answer to make the query look like below and you can then accept his answer :-)

```
select
  min(request_id),
  session_id,
  group_concat(topic_id order by request_id asc separator ' ,') as topics
from requests
group by session_id
having topics like '5000 ,%';
```

If there can be sessions like '5000 ,5000' (i.e. one session with more than one request, but only one topic) then you'd have to add `and count(distinct topic_id) > 1)` to the HAVING clause.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, your answer looks promising. But I can't transfer it to my problem, because it actually already contains a JOIN statement (I didn't mentioned it before, to make the question not overcomplicated). I updated the question.

Comment: @LarsVegas: See my update. Gouda Elalfy's way is the most simple way to solve this.

Comment: Thorsten, I used your second suggestion and it worked perfectly!
@Gouda Elalfy: I updated your solution. Please accept the peer review. Otherwise I will accept Thorstens solution. Thank you both for your help!